# Getting database usage of all the database at once in Sybase

Tags: sybase

How can I get the database usage of all the databases at once?

`sp_spaceused` and `sp_helpdb <dbname>` only gives the usage one at a time.

I use the Sybase Central client.

Comment: logsegment_freepages is invalid column in ASE16

Answer (score 3):

Below is the script that I use --- `master..sysdatabases`&  `master..sysusages`

```
--- Source : http://benohead.com/sybase-size-of-data-and-log-segments-for-all-databases/

select db_name(d.dbid) as db_name,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap != 4 then u.size/1048576.*@@maxpagesize end )) as data_size,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap != 4 then size - curunreservedpgs(u.dbid, u.lstart, u.unreservedpgs) end)/1048576.*@@maxpagesize) as data_used,
ceiling(100 * (1 - 1.0 * sum(case when u.segmap != 4 then curunreservedpgs(u.dbid, u.lstart, u.unreservedpgs) end) / sum(case when u.segmap != 4 then u.size end))) as data_used_pct,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap = 4 then u.size/1048576.*@@maxpagesize end)) as log_size,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap = 4 then u.size/1048576.*@@maxpagesize end) - lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",d.dbid)/1048576.*@@maxpagesize) as log_used,
ceiling(100 * (1 - 1.0 * lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",d.dbid) / sum(case when u.segmap in (4, 7) then u.size end))) as log_used_pct 
from master..sysdatabases d, master..sysusages u
where u.dbid = d.dbid  and d.status not in (256,4096)
group by d.dbid
order by db_name(d.dbid)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably create a .sql script that can run and return the value for multiple commands.

A script can be easily created using the following format:

```
set nocount on
select "sp_helpdb " + name + char(10) + "exec " + name + "..sp_spaceused" + char(10) + "go"
go
```

This will print out a list of commands that looks like this:

```
sp_helpdb DATABASE_01
exec DATABASE..sp_spaceused
go
sp_helpdb DATABASE_02
exec DATABASE..sp_spaceused
go
...
```

This output can be captured into a script file, and then executed all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Kin's query works well, unless there are incorrect entries in sysusages. I have run into that error. Sybase automatically ignores the bad entries, but this script could be thrown off. By checking if the vdevno is >= 0 will make sure all counted devices are real / usable devices.

I changed the script like so:

```
select db_name(d.dbid) as db_name,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap != 4 and vdevno >= 0 then (u.size/1048576.)*@@maxpagesize end )) as data_size_MB,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap != 4 and vdevno >= 0 then size - curunreservedpgs(u.dbid, u.lstart, u.unreservedpgs) end)/1048576.*@@maxpagesize) as data_used_MB,
ceiling(100 * (1 - 1.0 * sum(case when u.segmap != 4 and vdevno >= 0 then curunreservedpgs(u.dbid, u.lstart, u.unreservedpgs) end) / sum(case when u.segmap != 4 then u.size end))) as data_used_pct,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap = 4 and vdevno >= 0 then u.size/1048576.*@@maxpagesize end)) as log_size_MB,
ceiling(sum(case when u.segmap = 4 and vdevno >= 0 then u.size/1048576.*@@maxpagesize end) - lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",d.dbid)/1048576.*@@maxpagesize) as log_used_MB,
ceiling(100 * (1 - 1.0 * lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",d.dbid) / sum(case when u.segmap in (4, 7) and vdevno >= 0 then u.size end))) as log_used_pct 
from master..sysdatabases d, master..sysusages u
where u.dbid = d.dbid  and d.status != 256
group by d.dbid
order by db_name(d.dbid)
```

Comment: `segmap` is a bitmap and therefore should be tested with bitwise operations, eg, your query could mishandle entries where `segmap` = 5/6/12 (log segment combined with system/default/user-defined segments) [and, yes, Kin's answer has the same issue]; also keep in mind that `vdevno` was introduced with ASE 15.0, so the query will generate a syntax error if used in pre-ASE 15.0 (eg, ASE 11.x/12.x)